# Rust Create Test Setup

Tags: unit-testing, rust

I'm learning Rust with unit tests and the below code is the solution of [this problem](https://exercism.org/tracks/rust/exercises/health-statistics) with slight changes.

```
struct User {
    name: String,
    age: u8,
    weight: f32
}

impl User {
    fn new(name: String, age: u8, weight: f32) -> Self {
        User {name: name, age: age, weight: weight}
    }

    fn get_name(&self) -> &str {
        &self.name
    }

    fn get_age(&self) -> u8 {
        self.age
    }

    fn get_weight(&self) -> f32 {
        self.weight
    }

    fn set_name(&mut self, new_name: String) {
        self.name = new_name
    }

    fn set_age(&mut self, new_age: u8) {
        self.age = new_age
    }

    fn set_weight(&mut self, new_weight: f32) {
        self.weight = new_weight
    }
}


#[test]
fn test_user_get_name() {
    let user = User::new(String::from("Bob"), 20, 150.23);
    assert_eq!(user.get_name(), "Bob")
}

#[test]
fn test_user_set_name() {
    let mut user = User::new(String::from("John"), 24, 150.23);
    user.set_name("Jane".to_string());    // no performance cost compared to String::from
    assert_eq!(user.get_name(), "Jane")
}

#[test]
fn test_user_get_age() {
    let user = User::new(String::from("Bob"), 20, 150.23);
    assert_eq!(user.get_age(), 20)
}

#[test]
fn test_user_set_age() {
    let mut user = User::new(String::from("Bob"), 20, 150.23);
    user.set_age(25);
    assert_eq!(user.get_age(), 25)
}

#[test]
fn test_user_get_weight() {
    let user = User::new(String::from("Bob"), 20, 150.23);
    assert_eq!(user.get_weight(), 150.23)
}

#[test]
fn test_user_set_weight() {
    let mut user = User::new(String::from("Bob"), 20, 150.23);
    user.set_weight(160.8);
    assert_eq!(user.get_weight(), 160.8)
}
```

I can execute tests and all of them pass:

```
rustc --test health_stats.rs --verbose -o health_stats_test
./health_stats_test
```

How can I create a `setup()` function with a mutable object like:

```
let mut user = User::new(String::from("Bob"), 20, 150.23);
```

so that I can call `get` and `set` methods in tests without duplicating code?

Comment: That's not a great teaching example. Getters and setters aren't idiomatic in Rust. They can be useful sometimes, but they shouldn't be added indiscriminately like one does in, say, Java. If this code were under code review I would say to get rid of them and just make the fields `pub`. That would get rid of the impetus to create a `setup()` method.

Comment: You can do that, but this is not a good idea. Do not share state between tests unless they're supposed to work on the same data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, some minor nitpicks:

- Your test functions get compiled into your release build.
  Use the pattern described in the [rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/testing/unit_testing.html) to layout your tests.
- I made your `struct` and all of your `impl`s `pub`, otherwise they are pretty pointless and I didn't like the warnings :)

So, with that out of the way, lets actually talk about the tests.

There is no built-in mechanism in Rust for test `setup`/`teardown`, but it's very easy to implement yourself. You can just write a simple `setup()` function that returns a context object with a `drop` implementation for teardown.

You could create your user and store it in the context object. Further, you can run any kinds of side effects. I'll demonstrate this here by printing some messages.

Here, this is kind of how I would implement a `setup`/`teardown` mechanism:

```rust
pub struct User {
    name: String,
    age: u8,
    weight: f32,
}

impl User {
    pub fn new(name: String, age: u8, weight: f32) -> Self {
        User {
            name: name,
            age: age,
            weight: weight,
        }
    }

    pub fn get_name(&self) -> &str {
        &self.name
    }

    pub fn get_age(&self) -> u8 {
        self.age
    }

    pub fn get_weight(&self) -> f32 {
        self.weight
    }

    pub fn set_name(&mut self, new_name: String) {
        self.name = new_name
    }

    pub fn set_age(&mut self, new_age: u8) {
        self.age = new_age
    }

    pub fn set_weight(&mut self, new_weight: f32) {
        self.weight = new_weight
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    struct TestContext {
        user: User,
    }

    impl Drop for TestContext {
        fn drop(&mut self) {
            println!("Test teardown ...");
        }
    }

    fn setup() -> TestContext {
        println!("Test setup ...");

        TestContext {
            user: User::new(String::from("Bob"), 20, 150.23),
        }
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_user_get_name() {
        let ctx = setup();
        assert_eq!(ctx.user.get_name(), "Bob")
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_user_set_name() {
        let mut ctx = setup();
        ctx.user.set_name("Jane".to_string()); // no performance cost compared to String::from
        assert_eq!(ctx.user.get_name(), "Jane")
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_user_get_age() {
        let ctx = setup();
        assert_eq!(ctx.user.get_age(), 20)
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_user_set_age() {
        let mut ctx = setup();
        ctx.user.set_age(25);
        assert_eq!(ctx.user.get_age(), 25)
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_user_get_weight() {
        let ctx = setup();
        assert_eq!(ctx.user.get_weight(), 150.23)
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_user_set_weight() {
        let mut ctx = setup();
        ctx.user.set_weight(160.8);
        assert_eq!(ctx.user.get_weight(), 160.8)
    }
}
```

```
> cargo test
running 6 tests
test tests::test_user_get_age ... ok
test tests::test_user_get_name ... ok
test tests::test_user_get_weight ... ok
test tests::test_user_set_age ... ok
test tests::test_user_set_name ... ok
test tests::test_user_set_weight ... ok

test result: ok. 6 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 0.00s
```

If you add `--nocapture`, you can see the output of the setup/teardown `println` messages:

```
> cargo test -- --nocapture
running 6 tests
Test setup ...
Test teardown ...
Test setup ...
Test teardown ...
Test setup ...
Test teardown ...
Test setup ...
Test teardown ...
test tests::test_user_get_age ... okTest setup ...
Test setup ...
Test teardown ...
Test teardown ...

test tests::test_user_get_name ... ok
test tests::test_user_get_weight ... ok
test tests::test_user_set_age ... ok
test tests::test_user_set_weight ... ok
test tests::test_user_set_name ... ok

test result: ok. 6 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 0.00s
```

---

### Important: Side effects

By default, `cargo test` runs tests in parallel on multiple threads. If your `setup`/`teardown` methods have side effects that aren't thread-safe, you might want to force single-threaded test execution with the `--test-threads 1` flag:

```
> cargo test -- --nocapture --test-threads 1
running 6 tests
test tests::test_user_get_age ... Test setup ...
Test teardown ...
ok
test tests::test_user_get_name ... Test setup ...
Test teardown ...
ok
test tests::test_user_get_weight ... Test setup ...
Test teardown ...
ok
test tests::test_user_set_age ... Test setup ...
Test teardown ...
ok
test tests::test_user_set_name ... Test setup ...
Test teardown ...
ok
test tests::test_user_set_weight ... Test setup ...
Test teardown ...
ok

test result: ok. 6 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 0.00s
```